# Create web socket without a listener on Rest api or client initializing web socket request

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, rest

When a client connects to a Rest API server, is it possible to create a Web Socket on the Rest API server without creating a listener on the Rest Api server or without the client doing web socket initialization?

Comment: Do you want to receive connections on the REST API or connect from it to an external server?

Comment: I want to receive connections on the Rest API from clients say Angularjs, asp.net web applications and then Create a Web Socket to those clients. hope this helps

Comment: You need to listen then, if no there's no way to receive an incomming request.

Comment: Rest API receives and successfully responds to client connections. Rest API now needs to create a Web Socket using that client Info

Comment: The server can't create a connection to the client, WebSockets are initiated by the client, so the server must be listening for websocket requests.

Comment: If you only want some clients to be able to connect to the socket server I would create the websocket listener at the API boot, then when the client wants to connect to the server it requests a temporary key, connects to the server and sends that validation key, in this way you can reject incomming sockets which aren't identified with a valid key.

Answer (score 1):

You want to initialize the websocket connection from the server? This is not possible. The initial handshake is in fact a normal HTTP request with special headers. So can you make an HTTP request from the server to the client? Nope!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: Just so I understood this correctly. If a Client browser connects to the Rest API, Rest API would take this client request and convert it into a Web Socket. This is not possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Prior to the websocket connection there is a handshake in which the client sends an HTTP/HTTPS request to the server. The server then answers with something very similar to HTTP/HTTPS. Then the communication switches to a persistent bidirectional connection which has nothing to do with HTTP/HTTPS anymore. Anyway what it is important is that the first request of the handshake always goes from client to server. You cannot reverse it.

Comment: Yes Sir. You understood my question perfectly. Now After the server responds to the Client, I want the server to take that client info and create a web socket to that underlying client. I don't see any example anywhere